# Testing Internet connection at regular intervals

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a certain website is online every 3 seconds.

If the connection exists and the site is online, I want to show "Connected" alert every 3 seconds, but if there's no connection or the site is not online, I want to show "Not connected" alert, also every 3 seconds.

I tried this:

```
var myURL = "http://www.example.com/";

function testConnection(url) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() { alert("Connected!");}   
    xmlhttp.onerror = function() { alert("Not Connected"); }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var tickingClock = setInterval(testConnection(myURL), 3000);
```

This, however, results in an alert only appearing once. What should I change in this snippet tp make it do what I want it to do?

Comment: Something you might want to look into instead of polling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: I see you are doing well. In this case, the network is busy re-establishing connection between client and server: persistent connection would be more effective here, have a look at this tutorial about websockets: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the function, rather than putting a reference to the function in your `setInterval` statement. The proper method would be:

```
var tickingClock = setInterval(function() { testConnection(myURL); }, 3000);
```

`setInterval` accepts a function (or a string, but try to avoid using a string). Your code fires the `testConnection` method, then gives the return value as the argument to `setInterval`. But that return value is undefined, so the `setInterval` has nothing to do.

Comment: I see. Thank you, @Joe! What if I just added `return true;` and `return false` to onload and onerror functions, would that work, too?

Comment: No, those functions aren't the problem. The argument you pass into `setInterval` has to be the function that you want to execute. I'll edit with a different alternative, but it won't be as pretty.

Comment: Ugh... sorry, @Joe, I'm not grasping. Could you explain it to me in a little more detail? `testConnection` is a function, isn't it? Isn't that the function I want to execute? Sorry if the question sounds dumb, I just want to understand how it works.

Comment: Actually, I won't edit - I can't think of a different way. Remember what functions are. When you execute a function (by calling it with the parens), you get the result of that function. For example: `doubleThisNumber(5)` has the value of `10`. Anytime you call that code, all you get is `10`. But if you want a reference to that function, you just say `doubleThisNumber`, which gets you the function definition. Or if you want a reference to the function that calls it with 5, without actually executing it, you say `function() { return doubleThisNumber(5); }`.

Comment: `setInterval` accepts a function which it can call itself. If you call the function yourself, then you haven't given `setInterval` anything to do. You might way to read up a bit on javascript functions - most javascript libraries are heavy on using functions as "first-class citizens", which means you need to be comfortable nesting functions, passing functions as objects, etc.